# Form Recognizer cannot recognize single character

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using form recognizer custom model with labelling tool, https://fott.azurewebsites.net/.
I am trying to OCR NRIC card, it have gender information, value like 'M' or 'F'.
But, in labelling tool, cannot OCR this value in some images.
May I know the root cause? because it is single character?? or may be other reason?
and any way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If OCR did not detect the character than you won't be able to label it in the FOTT tool. This seems like an OCR miss on the gender value single character.

Comment: could you also try https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/  which has a more recent OCR version?

Answer (score 0):

could you also try https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/  which has a more recent OCR version?